# Value of $2^{-1-i}$ in the complex

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms

I am trying to find the value of $2^{-1-i}$.

I rewrite it like this, $2^{-1-i}=e^{\ln(2)(-1-i)}={1\over{e^{\ln2}e^{i\ln2}}}=1/2$

Since $e^{i\ln2}=e^{Re(i\ln2)}=e^0=1$.

This looks way nicer than it should be, I think, can anyone tell me where I go wrong, and maybe a good way to do this problem?

Thank you for any input.

Comment: $e^{it} = \cos t + i \sin t$ so $e^{i \ln 2} = \ldots$?

Comment: I also know about that way too, but why does it not just equal to 1 in this case?

Comment: Because $\cos \ln 2 \not= 1$.

Comment: Your statement that $e^{i\ln2} = e^{\text{Re}(i\ln2}$ is incorrect. Recall that, for real $a$ and $b$, we have $e^{a+bi}=e^a\cos b + i e^a\sin b$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a multi-valued function. For each $k\in\mathbb{Z}$, you can write
$$2^{-1-i} = e^{(-1-i)(\ln 2 + 2\pi ki)} = e^{-\ln 2 + 2\pi k + i(-\ln2 - 2\pi k)}
= \boxed{\frac12 e^{2\pi k}\cos\ln 2 - i\frac12 e^{2\pi k}\sin\ln 2}$$

Answer (score 2):

$$2^{-1-i}=2^{-1}\cdot2^{-i}=\frac12\cdot(e^{\text{Log}2})^{-i}=\frac{e^{i(-\text{Log}2)}}2$$

where $\displaystyle\text{Log}_ez=\log_ez+2n\pi i$

Now, use [Euler Formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerFormula.html)

Comment: This is incomplete. You have chosen a specific branch. There are countably many distinct values.

Comment: @MPW, please find the edited version

Answer (score 1):

$e^{iln2} \neq e^{Re(iln2)}$ 
$$e^{iln2}=cos(ln2)+isin(ln2)$$
and, $$2^{-1-i}=\frac{(cos(ln2)-isin(ln2))}{2}$$
As u expected this doesnt look good.